# Difference between m1 and m2 generic method in Java

Tags: java, generics

Can someone help me to understand the difference between m1() and m2() generic method.

```
class C1 {
 <T extends Number> void m1(List<T> list){
        System.out.println(list);
        for (T t : list){
            System.out.println(t);

        }
    }

    void m2(List<? extends Number> list){
        for(Number n :list){

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What aspect of the differences do you need help with?

Answer (score 2):

There is no functional difference between these 2 snippets. They do the same thing, are equally flexible, have the same signatures, and basically compile down to the precise same class file.

The first snippet says: There is some type; we restrict it so that it is either `java.lang.Number` or some subtype thereof. Then, this type shows up twice: Once as the type param on a list (so, it's a list of numbers, or a list of integers, or a list of doubles, etc), and once as the type of the variable when we iterate through each element in the list. All that you can tell about the t variable in `for (T t : list)` is that it is at the very least `java.lang.Number` but that's all you know.

In the second snippet you say: We have a list of either `java.lang.Number` or any subtype thereof. All we do with this list is iterate through it, at which point it's fine to state that you can be sure that the items that fall out when you iterate through this list are at the very least a `java.lang.Number`.

In both cases, the loop var (`T t` in the first snippet, `Number n` in the second) are bound as `java.lang.Number` and can be used as a number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I knew that both will do the same thing. But just wanted to know to know will there be any difference in which scenarios to use m1 or m2 (just forget about the internal what method is doing)

Comment: @Vishal The ? form is simpler to understand and should be used here.